# Shipping method are not showing on front end magento ?

Tags: cart, shipping

I am using magento, and am new to magento! 
I have a problem that shipping method is not showing on magento frontend default theme page.

i have configure shipping method from it's backend and enable one of the shipping method (free shipping) too. 
But it's not showing on frontend ?

### Any solution please...

Some Snapshot of backend and frontend are are follows: 
[image]

[image]

above image it's should show shipping method of number 3 but not showing :( :( :(

Comment: First add simple product , then go to checkout page. May be your cart has downloadable or virtual product.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add simple product to cart, then go to checkout. No need shipping information and shipping method for downloadable or virtual product. Both product types are virtual that's why they need not to shipment.